# GAE Flask global variable persistent across browsers

Tags: python, google-app-engine, flask

Here's my Flask setup:

`main.py`

```
from flask import Flask
from app.views import main_bp

app = Flask(__name__)
app.register_blueprint(main_bp, url_prefix='')
```

`app.config.py` (Shortened with "..." for this example)

```
CONFIG = {
    'SITE_NAME': 'Test Site',
    'SSL': False,
    'DEBUG': True,
    'LOGGED_IN': False,
    ...
}
```

`views.py`

```
from config import CONFIG

@main_bp.route('/')
@main_bp.route('/<page_slug>/')
def fallback(page_slug='home'):
    # Check if logged in
    if CONFIG['LOGGED_IN']:
        return 'Logged In'
    else
        return 'Logged Out'
```

Now if I change `CONFIG['LOGGED_IN']` to `True` in one of my browsers (Let's say Google Chrome), and then open another browser to the website (Let's say Firefox), then I'm already logged in on both. If I then log out in Firefox and refresh Chrome, I'm logged out on both.

When I was using Django I never noticed a problem like this... my global CONFIG variable is persisting across browsers. Weird!

Do I need to make my CONFIG into a class? Maybe this only happens when running through dev_appserver.py and won't happen in production? I'm still learning, so please be nice! Thanks :)

Note: Please ignore the blatant security issues with this example. I assure you this is not how I plan to use this code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As davidism pointed out, I should not be storing variables that change per session as a global. I will instead decide on these variables after loading pertinent session variables like UID and Session ID.

Thanks.

Update: Athough, I find it interesting that Flask documentation would advocate setting globals via `g` (see: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/api/)